# Find the value of $z$ which satisfies the equation $z^{18}=(1+i)$ and which has the second smallest positive argument $θ$, $0<θ<2π$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having trouble figuring out where to begin.

I know that: $$a^z = \exp(z\log a)$$

but I don't think that applies here.

I also thought of maybe trying to start with the 18th root of $1+i$.

Help please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write 1+i in polar form. Then find the 18 18th square roots of the expression and decide for the desired one. If $1+i = re^{it}$ then the solutions for $z$ have the form $\sqrt[18]{r}e^{\frac i{18}(t + 2k\pi)}$, where $k=0,\ldots,17$.

Comment: So the polar form would be $$\sqrt2(cos(\frac\pi4)+isin(\frac\pi4))$$
I am confused with the next step. How do you find the 18 18th roots of this?

Comment: I wrote it. Why don't you read? ($e^{it}$ is a short form for $\cos(t) + i\sin(t)$)